# Polynomial divisible by unbounded primes with exponent one

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, factorization

Let $f(x)$ be squarefree polynomial with integer coefficients and
degree at least $3$.

Is it true that for all sufficiently large $n$, $f(n)$ is divisible
by prime $p$ with exponent one and $p$ is unbounded?

This fails for degree two by the Pell equation $x^2-1=a^3 y^2$.

abc and intuition imply it, but we are looking for unconditional result.

This is closely related to the following:

Must $f(x)$ be squarefull (powerful) finitely often?